# ¿Cómo crear un retardo de tiempo en una función en C?

Tags: c

Estoy creando una función en c para que me imprima por consola las letras de una palabra, pero quisiera que cada letra la imprimiera cada determinado tiempo, como haría para hacerle un retador a cada letra, este es el código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main(){
    char palabra[] = "Hola Mundo";
    for (int x = 0; x < strlen(palabra); x++){
        printf("%c", palabra[x]);
    }
}
```

Que funcion podría implementar para que cada letra se imprima cada determinado tiempo (ejemplo 3 segundos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `sleep` te permite añadir una pausa de N segundos:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void main(){
    char palabra[]="Hola Mundo";
    for(int x = 0; x < strlen(palabra); x++){
        printf("%c", palabra[x]);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Si 1 segundo te parece demasiado tiempo (y estás en Linux) puedes usar `usleep`. En este caso podrás indicar el tiempo en milisegundos,

Comment: pero unistd.h no es parte de la librería estandar, como hago para incluirla o donde descargarla, estoy en Linux

Comment: @Kelvin al contrario. Estando en Linux debería poder usarlo. En Windows es donde no podrías. https://tio.run/##PYzRCsIgGIXvfYofI3Csoq7duu4dYhf265pgKupiEHt2s5B9NwfO@Th4fCLmvNMWzSwVdLPVMcnTdCXk7bSEl9CWNR8CBZxEAC@MeARxH3p6c0ZQ/p9GF5i2CRbo4cxLdBBTMMqy6jelbNt69MOH4o@M7pEettNlaPhmRKOUZ5farGTN@Qs

Comment: @Mateo ok muchas gracias me funciono bien, y si estuviera en Windows como le haría para obtener el mismo resultado

Comment: @Mateo la función en el bucle al ejecutar se espera un rato y al final es que me muestra la palabra completa, yo quisiera que cada 1 segundo se muestre una letra en consola y sin salto de linea

Answer (score 0):

En Windows podes usar la función [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep). Toma los milisegundos que va a pausar el hilo cómo parámetro.

El código sería este:

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void main(){
    char palabra[]="Hola Mundo";
    for(int x = 0; x < strlen(palabra); x++){
        printf("%c", palabra[x]);
        // Espera 1 segundo
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

---

Puedes usar [macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor) para poder reutilizar el código en diferentes sistemas operativos. **Recuerda que no puedes darle a una macro el mismo nombre de otro símbolo.**

Por ejemplo:

```
#ifdef __unix__
#define wait(x) sleep(x)
#elif _WIN32
#define wait(x) Sleep(x * 1000)
#endif

// Espera 2s
wait(2);
```